# How to send photos from my Canon photo camera to my laptop via Wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless, canon, camera

I have a *Canon SX610 HS* photo camera which aims to be able to transfer data over wi-fi to my laptop.

I have no idea how to set that up. In the camera settings I have:

- **`NFC`**: `ON`
- **`Password`**: `OFF`
- **`Target History`**: `ON`
- **`Resize for Sending...`**: **`M2`** / No
- **`Change Device Nickname...`**: `SX610HS`
- **`Check MAC Address...`**: `D8:49:2F:98:3F:04`
- **Reset settings**

I guess that somehow I should connect from the laptop to my camera using the Device Nickname and MAC address, but I have no idea how.

How can I do that?

---

The manual says:

> The camera can connect via Wi-Fi to computers running the following
>   operating systems. For detailed system requirements and compatibility
>   information, including support in new operating systems, visit the
>   Canon website.
>
> - Windows 8/8.1
> - Windows 7 SP1
> - Mac OS X 10.9
> - Mac OS X 10.8.2 or later

Then it says to I need to install some piece of software. Obviously, they don't support Linux. Since I'm using Ubuntu and still hope there is a solution to do this on Ubuntu, I'm here. :)

Comment: You may need to check the camera's manual, and, since the question is not about Ubuntu, it is off topic here.

Comment: @mikewhatever I guessed it's obvious that it's about Ubuntu because I'm Ubuntu user. :) I detailed my question.

Comment: Tried running the whatever software they provide on Wine?

Comment: @muru I didn't, but that's a good idea... However, isn't there a native solution (even it's not official from CANON)?

Comment: Who knows? Also, who knows what Canon does? (And it's *Canon*, not *CANON*).

Comment: @muru I was wondering if there is a standard solution/workflow for sending photos over wi-fi and maybe Canon software just makes it friendlier for the user... Yes, it's *Canon*. `:-D`

Answer (score 2):

http://www.webupd8.org/2015/11/wirelessly-transfer-photos-from.html

Maybe this will help you. Just take a look at, I cant test it because my camera does not have wifi options.

Comment: Upvote from me, looks interesting, but it didn't work for me... Maybe I will contact the developer to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the camera provides a web interface to download pictures? To check try to connect to it via a web browser. After connecting the camera to your WiFi network, first find the camera's IP by:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.0.\*
```

(you might be on different network than `192.168.0.*`, check with `ifconfig`). If you aren't sure it's a right IP look for the MAC address `D8:49:2F:98:3F:04` you found in the settings by running command `arp`:

```
arp <some IP found by the nmap -sP>
```

e.g. `arp 192.168.0.1`. When confirmed, enter `http://<the IP found>` into a web browser.

You might play with scans `sudo nmap -O <IP>` and `nmap <IP>`, maybe you will find something useful, like a port number different than 80 (http).

Comment: *After connecting the camera to your WiFi network* –– how can I do that?

Comment: We have a router name and the password